# How can I refresh/update an Apache eChart based on data from a Sveltekit store?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, echarts, svelte-store, apache-echarts

I am trying to refresh/redraw an Apache eChart diagram based on data from a Sveltekit store, but I do not now how to do it.
I have also tried to use a button and feed a simple data object, but this also does not work.
The diagram is drawn properly with the onMount function, but I cannot get it to refresh/redraw, either reactively (with a store) or with a button (onClick)

```html
<!-- diagram.svelte -->
<script>
    import * as echarts from "echarts";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import { dummyStoreObj } from "$lib/stores.js";

    // the {data} property of the component from the OnLoad function of the +page.js
    export let data;

    // chart and options
    let myChart;
    let chartDom;
    let myChart_option;

    // Draw
    function drawChart() {
        chartDom = document.getElementById("chartDiv");
        myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);

        myChart_option = {
            dataset: {
                dimensions: ["start_time", "bucket", "folder", "name"],
                source: data,
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: "time",
                name: "date/time",
                nameLocation: "middle",
                splitLine: { show: true },
            },
            yAxis: {
                type: "category",
                name: "# folder",
                nameGap: "1",
                splitLine: { show: true },
            },
            series: [
                {
                    type: "scatter",
                    encode: {
                        x: "start_time",
                        y: "folder",
                    },
                },
            ],
        };

        // Initialise
        myChart_option && myChart.setOption(myChart_option);
    }

    const reDrawChart = async () => {
        console.log("Redraw called");

        // Set other source
        myChart_option.source = dummyStoreObj.data;

        // Redraw
        myChart.setOption(myChart_option);
    };

    // Draw Chart
    onMount(async () => {
        drawChart();
    });
</script>

<div>
    <!-- Button -->
    <button on:click={reDrawChart}>Redraw Chart</button>
</div>
<div id="chartDiv" />

<style>
    #chartDiv {
        height: 200px;
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid #141413;
    }
</style>
```

```js
// stores.js
const dummyStoreObj = {
    data: [{
        start_time: '2023-01-31T07:45:11.286491+01:00',
        bucket: 'bucketName',
        folder: 'folderName',
        filename: 'filename.txt'
    }]
};
export const storeData = writable(
    JSON.parse(
        dummyStoreObj || '',
    ));
```

The diagram should render properly with the data provided:

[echart render](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAmBDMWDOApmAFzJroWXoYQC2B0eUjpA2gOR64BOYA-pHrsANLHYAjAK4BjANZERYgGbAANhgLdF7aFiEBdYeSpU8wSd2kE2qE-i5ZeAutbEAmAAxuAzAFoPAIy-3gEAKh4A7MQALACsxAEBAHRuABwAbNEAnAEA1IHEHh4ixlRSckSkEjLyYAByegQldrAq6ppVbRrcDUJGLUoQqgyNnUMj9ElgAB5g7KUUAL7C-gtL_XbTAILTEHikti0UYACeIK7sgk0bR7C69FXYYAQA9FfNt3eNADLA0jjMKq0CAYDDDD63PAgVQQMDfCDQVxIWB4AAWwAA7qQwNxJARYIs1uhlkTYCcdnsDqTKKdzlV_s8AObAbgnCFHe4XADErTU3XZLU5AHEsCAqgEBXYoTC4QikSj0VjYDi8QTSSSWoRuBACPtYKxqRRDp9jmcLngGc8tDcTbAGNJgBoqbbNlUHE53jaXegTp0-Zp5t61SbCS1VosANxAA)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here, the primary one is that option is set in the wrong location. It should be:

```js
myChart_option.dataset.source = dummyStoreObj.data
```

`JSON.parse` on object like `dummyStoreObj` will throw an error, this looks like just an oversight and the `stores.js` code is incompatible in general because the object is exported.

Also, one should not query the DOM in Svelte, either use [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives-bind-this) on the element to get it, or use [actions](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action), e.g.

```js
function drawChart(node) { ...
```

```html
<div use:drawChart />
```